# Why is view.getHeigth return 0 on onResume()?

Tags: android, android-button

its my code. referButtun is imageButton

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    referButtun.getHeight();
    Log.d("Base",""+referButtun.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: There are many duplicate questions and answers for this, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4393612/534471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how you should do it:

```
final ViewTreeObserver vto = referButtun.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("Base",""+referButtun.getHeight());

        // don't forget to remove the listener, we don't need it just this one time
        vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

As an alternative you could use

```
referButtun.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Base",""+referButtun.getHeight());
    }
});
```