# View disappear after changing the parameters in android

Tags: android, android-view

I add a custom view dynamically,but when I change the parameters (height,width), the view dissapear or if i just add it with the standard parameters it works normally.What's the problem?
I'm trying to add [the parts of this](http://android-layouts.com/layout/benjamin-ferrari/2011/05/30/segmented-control) dynamically and affect new parameters to the parts.

xml code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/prog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:textAlignment="center" >
</RadioGroup>
```

Implementation code:

```
bar = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.prog);
int width = bar.getWidth();
RadioGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(width / 2,
                    height);
SegmentedControlButton part = new SegmentedControlButton(getActivity());
part.setLayoutParams(lparams);
bar.addView(part);
```

with one part it works but with 2 parts it disappears.
I tried to check the value of width and it's `0` but i call the method in `OnViewCreated` so normally the view is prepared there.

PS: I use a fragment
**UPDATE:**
I tried this implementation in `OnViewCreated` but still `0`:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = bar.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                width = bar.getWidth();



            }
        });
```

Comment: Some code demonstrating the problem would be very helpful here.

Comment: I would use DDMS to dump the View hierarchy and check for your missing View. If it's there, what is the width an height? Is `bar.getWidth()` returning what you expect?

Comment: yes because i tried 2 ways, the first one with buttons (+) and (-) to add and to remove parts, it works perfectly but when i use the classic way which is to simply call the method it disappears

Comment: You can get the width of the bar by `bar.getWidth()` and then make RadioGroup.LayoutParams with that `width` ( or `width/n`).

Comment: that's what i do, look at the code

Comment: Are you calling this in `onCreate()`, or any other method that runs before the views are actually measured and laid out? At that point, the width/height of them will be `0`.

Comment: i call the method in OnviewCreated but i checked now that the width is null!! how to fix that?

Comment: try this : lp =part.getLayoutParams();
lp.setWidth()\Height();
part.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: ALready tried, the app crashes with a NPE

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `width` field. 
Geobits is right, the width & height properties are set once the views are created and get measured. You can use [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) .Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use ViewTreeObserver to get the non-zero and non-null width of the bar. Example on how to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393612/when-can-i-first-measure-a-view).

You will have to replace

```
RadioGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(width / 2, height);
```

with

```
RadioGroup.LayoutParams lparams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(0, height, 1.0);
```

By setting layout_weight property to 1, you don't have to do width/n etc. You just keep adding parts to the bar and the width of parts should automatically be set.

HTH.

Comment: I hope you are measuring the bar width in your fragment class and not the activity class. Also, OnViewStateRestored is called the last, i believe - even later than OnViewCreated. You could see if you get a non-zero width there.

Comment: still a zero even with the changes

Comment: what about height? is that zero as well?