# how to animate new item in listview

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

i made code that populate listView from EditText view and enter it on button and it all work, BUT when i want to animate new item, that i just entered from EditText i can not do it, because i can not capture moment when listView get that new View.
Here how that look:

```
listaRadnikaArray.add(0,novoIme.getText().toString());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(listaRadnikaArray);    
LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.listview_podesavanje, null);
View noviRadnikView = lvRadnici.getChildAt(0);        //this return null or wrong view                                              
noviRadnikView.setAlpha(0);                           // because  listView lvRadnici do not have that new view jet.                           
noviRadnikView.animate().setDuration(500).alpha(1);      // why????
```

can anyone, please , explain to me what is a problem.

Comment: M sure each time you add a new item its the last poaition it takes. Kip store of the position and in the getview method compare the position of the new item and getviews position. If same animate view

Comment: tnx I did put position on first on 
deliberately, because i want to put new item on top of list, and that is a part that work just fine. do you want to tell me that listView delay update because i do that? i do have custom array adapter that have hashMap for order in ListAray.

Comment: no thats not the reason why it doesnt animate. :)

Comment: Is the animation inside the adapter??? If not try putting it inside the adapter

Comment: thanks mate, but that is not reason for this problem. after 2 day research i found that best way to work around this problem is using viewTreeObserver class.

Comment: Glad u found the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here some solution of this problem 
[How can you tell when a layout has been drawn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733813/how-can-you-tell-when-a-layout-has-been-drawn)
or 
[When Can I First Measure a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393612/when-can-i-first-measure-a-view)

or there is example from DevByts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wyhY68esZY

and who ever put negativ vote on question is noob, because i spend a lot of time to find solution and it is not simple problem.