# Pass in activity and listen for views inflated

Tags: android, view, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am currently designing a library.  This library presents UI elements that 'target' other elements already drawn on the screen.  It does this by passing in a View object.  However, Activities do not actually draw contents until later on in its lifecycle, making method calls like getHeight() and getWidth() useless.

Is there a way for me to perhaps pass in the instance of an activity (as a weakReference for good measure), to one of my library's class and 'listen' for when the contents have been drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use viewTreeObserver class .Register this observer and you will get a callback after the view has been drawn.

[When Can I First Measure a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393612/when-can-i-first-measure-a-view)