# Setting window layout after calling setContentView()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-windowmanager, android-rendering

I am creating an activity that as a dialog format: it does not cover the whole screen, but only part of it. What I did was in the onCreate() method of this activity, after calling setContentView(), I call:

```
window.setLayout(windowWidthInDp, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

And it does not work. I need to do the following instead to make it work:

```
window.getDecorView().post(new Runnable() { 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        window.setLayout(windowWidthInDp, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    } 
});
```

Again, this is AFTER setContentView() is called. 
Why do I have to pose it into the message queue instead of calling it directly? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the content view just gives the layout to the Android framework. The layout hasn't yet been fully configured. This doesn't happen until the Android framework gets control back (ie: in the next event loop). This won't happen until the `onCreate()` method ends.

By posting your code to a `Handler`, you delay the execution of that code until after the Android framework has fully configured the layout.

Comment: Thank you for replying! Is there some other signal for the layout being fully configured (other than the onCreate() method is returned)?

Comment: Some people are using `ViewTreeObserver's addOnGlobalLayoutListener()`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393612/when-can-i-first-measure-a-view for more information. Here someone suggests using `ViewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener()`

Comment: Noted. Thanks you!