# Multiple images in edit text Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-image, android-gallery

I am trying to replicate the text message application of Android Application, where the requirement is to send multiple images in one message.

I am able to put one image in edit text field. However, I am not sure how we can put multiple images in edit text?

If it is not possible, what is the another way to do it?

Someone has mentioned in following link that need to use relative layout with gallery and textview.

[How do I insert multiple image in Edit Text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572678/how-do-i-insert-multiple-image-in-edit-text-in-android)

Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement but you can add 6 drawables,  `drawableTop, drawableBottom, drawableLeft, drawableRight, drawableStart, drawableEnd`   and you can set them dynamically using `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method on any view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a

[LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)

It is a Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on top.

Comment: If I used LayerDrwable, then I am able to add multiple images. But I want to have textview with each image. For your reference, I have attached the screenshot at below link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_xgCwfb-GVmcEZ3UjFuanlmNE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my requirements:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_xgCwfb-GVmcEZ3UjFuanlmNE0/edit?usp=sharing

How can we use LayerDrawable here? I am new to Android. Would you please share some more details? How can I add multiple images on attach button?