# How to make a double gradient with XML (iphone like)

Tags: android, gradient

How can I make this kind of drawable gradient with XML?

[image: Double gradient image]

I can do a simple gradient from color A to color B but i don't know how to combine two gradients in the same drawable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-gradient shapes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes)

Comment: Done , thanks for suggesting it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found a solution with a layer-list which is good enough for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- First part is a gradient -->
    <item android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp"> 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#9dcbf6"
                android:endColor="#177ee6" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Second part is plain color. Slightly transparent -->
    <item android:top="1sp" android:bottom="20sp" > 
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#10ffffff"/>
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The middle is set to 20 sp because the container has a 40sp height , but you can adjust to your will by editing : `android:bottom="20sp"`

Answer (score 12):

You can have three colors in a gradient.  A start color, end color and a center color.

```
<gradient
        android:angle="integer"
        android:centerX="integer"
        android:centerY="integer"
        android:centerColor="integer"
        android:endColor="color"
        android:gradientRadius="integer"
        android:startColor="color"
        android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"]
        android:usesLevel=["true" | "false"] />
```

Alternatively you can use a LayerList Drawable and just piece them together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but using centerColor don't seems to be the solution. Looks at my question again , i added some informations

Comment: Then you'll have to move on to the second half of may answer and make two gradients and use a LayerList.

Comment: Don't seems possible to easily adjust a shape to 50% of height. i will probably use a stretchable image. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @grunk You are right, you wouldn't be able to get that crisp line where one of the gradients ends at 50% of the drawable's height.  Others might find it useful to know that you CAN specify top/right/bottom/left on each <item> in your <layer-list> but unfortunately, you can only provide a dimension like 50dp, not a relative value like 50%.  That makes them scale poorly, which kind of defeats the point of defining a drawable this way (IMO.)