# Android Gradient drawable color change

Tags: android, colors, gradient, shapes

I have a shape drawable in the drawable folder. Here is XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="#4D0418" 
        android:centerColor="#5F031D"
        android:endColor="#7D0227" 
        android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

Now I want to change the startColor, centerColor, endColor from the java code in the runtime. How it is possible to change?

Comment: You should be able to do it using Java reflection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no API to do this. I'll add one to a future Android release.

Comment: Is there anyway to recreate the total drawable through java code without using any XML?

Comment: I have created a GradientDrawable which is substitute of <gradient></gradient>. But how can I set it to any shape? Should I use ShapeDrawable for that? if it is, then how I can set my GradientDrawable to that ShapeDrawable?

Comment: GradientDrawable is a substitute for both <shape/> and <gradient/>

Comment: GradientDrawable doesn't appear to have anything equivalent to the ShapeDrawable's setShaderFactory method, [which can be used to create a gradient with more than just 3 colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes). Hmm. :-/

Comment: This appears to be in [API 16](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#setColors(int[])).