# get color of oval shaped view

Tags: android

In android I am creating views that I have given an oval shape and a solid color. Now I want to dynamically get and set the color of the circle. But the getBackground() returns a GradientDrawable, which [has no methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925978/android-gradient-drawable-color-change) for getting the color. Is there any (easy) way to do it anyway?

I prefer to not use a canvas, because I am working with a lot of elements that are all views, which makes it easier.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#ffff3333"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
Try this :

Get the bitmap using something like the getDrawingCache() 
and use that bitmap i.e., src as below

```
Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    for(int x = 0;x < bitmap.getWidth();x++)
        for(int y = 0;y < bitmap.getHeight();y++)
            int pixelColor = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

The pixelColor value will consists of the color of each and every pixel of your image.

Comment: It works the first time. Then I set the color to something else with .setBackgroundColor(int), and try to get the color again. But then it is not the color that I set it to, but the original color.

Comment: could you edit what you did in your question so that we here can check out the logic