# setColor method of GradientDrawable drawing different color

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapedrawable

I have a `shape` in `layer-list` and my goal is to change color of the `shape` programmatically at runtime. I have String for HEX code and I used `Color.parseColor()` to parse it and I passed to setColor method. Whenever I run the application it shows different color then I expect.

Here is my code for XML file :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item 
    android:id="@+id/lvbg"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape
        android:id="@+id/listview_background"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size
            android:height="220dp"
            android:width="600dp" >
        </size>

        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"></solid>

        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is my code in `CustomAdapter` :

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_info_selection_fragment_icon, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.collegeBG=(LayerDrawable)convertView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rectangle);
holder.bg = (GradientDrawable)holder.collegeBG.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.lvbg);
String color = "#FF" + rowItem.getCollegeColor();
holder.bg.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
```

For example when I put `#FF1D0A63` I get black or brown, totally different colors.
Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `rowItem.getCollegeColor()`?

Comment: Color codes in HEX format such as `232323` , `1D0A63` , `000000`

Comment: When I print the `color` there is no problem I get expected HEX results. `#FF232323` `#FF1D0A63` `#FF000000` and more. I guess the problem is about reaching 'shape' element in layer list. I am not sure if I'm reaching to 'shape' correctly

Comment: Reading this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925978/android-gradient-drawable-color-change) I'm not sure it's possible... It's an old post but there have been no updates.

Answer (score 4):

I still don't know what the problem is but I realized that when I use `layer-list` in xml and assign it as background to a view, and try to change color of a `shape` in `layer-list` I am having this problem.

So I solved it separating my background `shape` from `layer-list`.

I put my background `shape` to another file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <size
        android:height="220dp"
        android:width="600dp" >
    </size>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" > </solid>
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

And I assigned it as a background to a `TextView`.

The reason I used `layer-list` was to combine 2-3 shapes and make them gradient and give them rounded corners. Instead I used `View` and `TextView` and assigned shapes to them as background and it worked.

Here is my new `CustomAdapter`:

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_info_selection_fragment_icon, null);
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.tvBackground = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectionCollegeBackground);
GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) holder.tvBackground.getBackground();


String color = "#FF" + rowItem.getCollegeColor();
background.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
holder.tvBackground.setBackground(background);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code...

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
gd.setStroke(3, Color.BLUE);
gd.setSize(w, h);
gd.setColors(new int[]{
   Color.RED,
   Color.GREEN,
   Color.YELLOW,
   Color.CYAN
});
gd.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
```