# can we make multi color gradient in xml for android background?

Tags: java, android, xml, image, background

I have been trying to make a multi-color background in XML but there only 3 option available start, center, end and specified angles. Can't we make backgrounds like this below..[image: multi color at different angle]

[image: multi color at different angle]

Can we make like this background in android ??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020530/using-a-gradientdrawable-with-more-than-three-colors-set and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes

Comment: can you tell me how ??

Comment: These are only two colors i believe. These gradients can be made.

Comment: no, in xml you can only use max 3 colors, if you need more, you have to use `android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable`

Comment: use several layers!

Answer (score 51):

According to [developers.android](https://developer.android.com/samples/GridViewPager/res/drawable/gradient.html)
you can... and this is the code they used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:endColor="#87CEEB"
    android:centerColor="#768087"
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

also [here's](http://www.singhajit.com/gradient-color-in-android/) a tutorial

hope this helps

Comment: I need multiple colors not only 3 .. but anyway i have i have done it thanks for help.

Comment: Tapan Kumar Patro please share what you've done to achieve it

Answer (score 43):

You cannot implement +3 gradient color in a xml file. But you can do it into your java/kotlin code with GradientDrawable class. This is the Java version, replace the array of colors with your colors ids.

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
                Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color1),
                        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color2),
                        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color3),
                        ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.color4)});

        findViewById(R.id.background).setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

Comment: Too late ... In my activity I have some `findelementbyid` and when I add your code to end of my code it produces error and those `findelementbyid` become red!

Answer (score 33):

This can be achieved by using vector graphics
i have made this background gradient in adobe illustrator and then import that vector asset as xml in to android studio and it works perfectly with the scalability of vectors

[image]

and here is the code for this vector/xml drawable

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="987.3dp"
    android:height="870.3dp"
    android:viewportWidth="987.3"
    android:viewportHeight="870.3">
    <path android:pathData="M0,870l0,-870l987,0l0,870z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endX="493.5"
                android:endY="870"
                android:startX="493.5"
                android:startY="2.6645353E-14"
                android:type="linear">
                <item
                    android:color="#FF0000FF"
                    android:offset="0" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FF6AFCFF"
                    android:offset="0.1974" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFE900D0"
                    android:offset="0.3786" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFFF7D15"
                    android:offset="0.5906" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFE6FF55"
                    android:offset="0.7513" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFED1E79"
                    android:offset="1" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

To show the gradient in a horizontal orientation, use the following xml code :

[image]

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="96dp"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">
    <path android:pathData="M0,870l0,-870l987,0l0,870z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient
                android:endX="99"
                android:endY="50"
                android:startX="1"
                android:startY="50"
                android:type="linear">
                <item
                    android:color="#FF0000FF"
                    android:offset="0" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FF6AFCFF"
                    android:offset="0.1974" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFE900D0"
                    android:offset="0.3786" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFFF7D15"
                    android:offset="0.5906" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFE6FF55"
                    android:offset="0.7513" />
                <item
                    android:color="#FFED1E79"
                    android:offset="1" />
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>
</vector>
```

Read more about VectorDrawable gradients here - https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-gradients-part1/

Comment: Do you know what I need to change here (if possible) to make this background horizontally?

Comment: no you have to recreate the vector file from scratch it's as easy as pie

Comment: Wonderful answer, i'd like to upvote it more if i could. Didn't occur to me to user vectors for this.

Comment: Agreed, would be good to provide guidance on how to rotate horizontal.

Answer (score 8):

Create a new xml file in drawable and copy this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient android:startColor="#9A0C0C"
          android:centerColor="#CE9908"
          android:endColor="#3091FF"
          android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<gradient
    android:endColor="#243638"
    android:centerColor="#3c6869"
    android:startColor="#7d695c"
    android:type="radial"
    android:centerX="100%"
    android:centerY="100%"
    android:gradientRadius="900dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create New xml file under drawable folder and follow the code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#1fa2ff"
            android:centerColor="#12d8fa"
            android:endColor="#a6ffcb"
            android:angle="45"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

In main.xml set your background to the new xml file created in drawable

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has this question in regards to how to achieve this kind of results with the new UI toolkit Jetpack Compose then it is fairly simple by way of using the [`Brush`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Brush) utility:

```kotlin
@Preview(
    device = Devices.PIXEL_4
)
@Composable
public fun GradientComposable() {
    val topRightCornerColor = Color(0xFF365d6a)
    val second = Color(0xFF126e87)
    val third = Color(0xFF769397)
    val fourth = Color(0xFF555361)
    val bottomLeftCornerColor = Color(0xFF4f4858)
    val angleBrush = Brush.linearGradient(
        colors = listOf(
            topRightCornerColor,
            second,
            third,
            fourth,
            bottomLeftCornerColor
        ), start = Offset(
            x = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
            y = 0f
        ), end = Offset(
            x = 0f,
            y = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        )
    )
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(brush = angleBrush)
            .fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

This creates a linear gradient from the top right most corner down to the left most corner (the offset sets the angle and direction, up or down).

The more colors are supplied at intervals between the first and last colours, the closer to the correct gradient you will get. Here I only use 5 colors.

The resulting background being as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with layer-list of radial gradients, then you set different opacity for different items

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can just use this extension function, code is taken by @Pelanes

```
fun ImageView.setGradientDrawable(colorArray: IntArray) {
val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colorArray
)
this.background = gradientDrawable}
```