# Draw specific gradient programmatically

Tags: android, gradient

I want to draw a specific gradient programmatically - something like this:[image: drawable]

Could you please help me?
I investigated that I can do

```
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
            new int[] {0xFF616261,0xFF131313});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
```

But the output gradient is linear, not like mine.

Thanks!

Comment: use LinearGradient class

Comment: i think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes