# Android gradient with straight line

Tags: java, android, gradient

I want to have a gradient like [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7HJW.png) image.

[image]

I have created this shape but even after trying so many times I couldn't achieve such type of gradient. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This is the work I've done:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/red"
        android:centerColor="@color/light_red"
        android:endColor="@color/light_red"
        android:angle="90"
        />
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Comment: Could you use a ninepatch instead?

Comment: I dont know how to make nine patch

Comment: my suggestion  - google it, you are technical person you should find your self instead of asking simple questions

Answer (score 0):

This link similar to your need [Multi-gradient shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes)

or

use this online tool http://angrytools.com/gradient/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sweep gradient for this! A sweep gradient looks [a bit like a cone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFaaA.png), but by offsetting it waaaaay to the left (via `centerX`), you can achieve the effect with a single gradient.

Here's how it looks (ignore the shape):
[image: sweep gradient]

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/red"
        android:endColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:centerX="-99"
        android:type="sweep" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```