# How to make fade between 3 or more colours on Android

Tags: java, android

**Colorfade**

I am looking for transition animation that:

- Fades between 3 (or more).
- Repeats
- And can be applied to `RelativeLayout`'s background or `LinearLayout`'s bacground

I have tried:

`TransitionDrawable` and `ColorDrawable`:

```
 relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen1);
    ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#7cc57a")), new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#CAC132")) , new ColorDrawable((Color.parseColor("#E79893")))};
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    trans.startTransition(7000);
```

But it only fades between two color and don't repeat...

*Is there any code that can solve this? Or should I add some* `whenCompleted()`-*method?*

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes

Comment: but what about the animation? That is good article about gradient but about colorfade...

Comment: *what about the colorfade

Comment: My bad. Then this will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android

Scroll a bit down.

Comment: RBK's answer looks just right, **but** where is "anim" declared and how to make that color hue change a lot more slower... But thanks alot for a tip:)

Comment: I will solved it :) i must write it first

Comment: I'm very interested in your solution.

Comment: Thank a lot guys:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example app and **ColorFader** class created to this purpose ( animate between many colors ) is available here - https://github.com/maciejsikora/ColorFader.

Simpler solution for this problem but only on 3 colors:

```
public class ColorChanger {


    private int from_color;
    private int to_color;
    private int currentColor;
    private int interval=1000;//default iterval
    private ValueAnimator colorAnimation;
    private int[] colors=new int[3];

    public ColorChanger(int color1, int color2, int color3){


        colors[0]=color1;
        colors[1]=color2;
        colors[2]=color3;

        this.currentColor=0;

        from_color=colors[0];
        to_color=colors[1];

    }


    public ColorChanger run(final View view){




        colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), from_color, to_color);
        colorAnimation.setDuration(this.interval);

        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            view.setBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
        }

        });

        colorAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


            from_color=colors[currentColor];



            if (currentColor+1>=colors.length){

                currentColor=0;

            }else{
                currentColor++;
            }

            to_color=colors[currentColor];

            //run again
            run(view);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

           }
        });


        colorAnimation.start();

        return this;

    }

    public void setIntervalMs( int ms){

        this.interval=ms;

    }

}
```

Example usage:

```
ColorChanger colorChanger = new ColorChanger(getResources().getColor(R.color.red),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

colorChanger.run(findViewById(R.id.content));
```

Comment: So should i put that colorchanger class code to my main activity?

Comment: Straight without creating new classes?

Comment: Create new file with class ColoChanger ( paste my code ) then use it in activity as i showed.

Comment: @PersonalHealth i created example app and better solution on github, link is in answer. Give me feedback if it fits Yours needs.

Comment: Its okay i solved my problem but ill mark yours as helpful thanks for helping!