# Gradual Colour Blend between multiple colours - Android

Tags: android, canvas, colors

I have a list of colours (generated from rgb values). I want to be able to draw all the colours to something on the screen at the same time. Ideally, the colours would blend through each change (typically the colour change will be gradual, but it is possible to have sudden changes) so that the colour change isn't abrupt. Eventually I'd like to be able to crop the result using another image, but my main concern is getting the colours drawn in the first place.

So something like this effect, except where the colours are defined by the ones in the array:

[image]

Comment: you want all the colors at the same time in one view or you want them one by one turning to another gradually. which one?

Comment: All at the same time like in the picture - edited to reflect this

Comment: so why don't you set this picture in background?

Comment: because i want the effect this image gives (I.e a gradual transition between colours) except i want the colours defined in the array not the fixed colours in the picture. My colours will change each time the user goes to this screen

Comment: i don't understand what you want

Comment: (after a bit more reading) What i really want is multiColoured linear gradients, where i can define the colours programatically

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes) may help you.