# Gradients in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, css, xml

I was designing UI in Figma for my Android Studio project. I created rectangle which had several gradients and solid color. How can I create the exact same rectangle in Android Studio? Below is the code in CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FCEFFF 0%, rgba(252, 239, 255, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(252, 239, 255, 0) 70.31%), linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 0%, rgba(252, 239, 255, 0) 63.02%), #D3AAF4;
```

I know I should use "solid" and "gradient" tags in XML but it doesn't work as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in an xml layout in your drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#FFF"
        android:endColor="#000"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: I know I should use "gradient" tag but in this case I need to have more than 1 gradient in the shape.

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381033/multi-gradient-shapes

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with custom shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:angle="45" //your angel
    android:endColor="#87CEEB" //first color
    android:centerColor="#768087" //second color
    android:startColor="#000" //last color
    android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```